# golang with SOAP

Tags: xml, parsing, soap, go

Bellow is the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

type Return struct {
    RequestId int
    DataCenterId string
    DataCenterVersion int
    StorageId string
}

type StorageReturn struct{
    Ret  Return `xml:"return"`
}

type Body struct {
    StrgRet StorageReturn `xml:"ns:createStorageReturn"`
}

type StorageResponse struct{
    XMLName xml.Name
    RespBody Body `xml:"S:Body"`
}


func main(){
   s = `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:createStorageReturn xmlns:ns2="http://ws.api.mysite.com/"><return><requestId>16660663</requestId><dataCenterId>ssrr-444tt-yy-99</dataCenterId><dataCenterVersion>12</dataCenterVersion><storageId>towrrt24903FR55405</storageId></return></ns2:createStorageReturn></S:Body></S:Envelope>`

    parser := xml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBufferString(s))
    envelope := new(StorageResponse)
    err = parser.DecodeElement(&envelope, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error in parsing")
        fmt.Printf("%v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", envelope)
}
```

It does print this ---

{XMLName:{Space:http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Local:Envelope} RespBody:{StrgRet:{Ret:{RequestId:0 DataCenterId: DataCenterVersion:0 StorageId:}}}}

no idea  why.

I am bad at xml parsing and i do not understand what i am doing wrong. For further reference I mention here that this is a response from a SOAP call that I want to parse. The calling and receiving parts are omitted as they are working fine and no problem. Problem is just the parsing of the return XML.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

As per request of Goku. Here is a working version of the code I posted above

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

type Return struct {
    RequestId int `xml:"requestId"`
    DataCenterId string `xml:"dataCenterId"`
    DataCenterVersion int `xml:"dataCenterVersion"`
    StorageId string `xml:"storageId"`
}

type StorageReturn struct{
    Ret  Return `xml:"return"`
}

type Body struct {
    StrgRet StorageReturn `xml:"createStorageReturn"`
}

type StorageResponse struct{
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Envelope"`
    RespBody Body `xml:"Body"`
}


func main(){
   s := `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:createStorageReturn xmlns:ns2="http://ws.api.mysite.com/"><return><requestId>16660663</requestId><dataCenterId>ssrr-444tt-yy-99</dataCenterId><dataCenterVersion>12</dataCenterVersion><storageId>towrrt24903FR55405</storageId></return></ns2:createStorageReturn></S:Body></S:Envelope>`

    v := StorageResponse{}  
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &v)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", v)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Self promotion: https://github.com/kylewolfe/simplexml (under development but I have used it for a few projects). Also, this will help you understand what's going in / out: https://github.com/ernesto-jimenez/httplogger

What you have printed is an empty struct (with default values) that has failed to unmarshal correctly, most likely due to namespace issues.

Comment: well I solved it for now. And I think that I understood the XML parsing better while doing so. Thanks for the pointers anyway.